# Why does the Youtube/Google API not return more than 5 replies?

Tags: c#, google-api, youtube-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Since a few days I have been using Youtube's (Google's) API 3.0 (.NET Google API Library)
Everything was going smooth until I stumbled across a problem. I've tried many methods to figure out why I got a low amount of info from my results.

What I am trying in the code down below, is requesting the first comment on a video.
Then with that first comment (CommentThread), I am trying to retrieve all the replies of users that reacted on this comment.

I have tried getting information before, it works fine. I could loadup the entire comment section. Except for more than 5 replies per CommentThread. (CommentThread is basicly a comment under a video, where some have replies.)

This is my code, I have modified it alot of times, but from the looks of it. This one should work.

```
        private static void searchReplies()
        {
            int count = 0;
            YouTubeService youtube = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { ApiKey = Youtube.API.KEY });
            List<string[]> comments = new List<string[]>();


            var commentThreadsListRequest = youtube.CommentThreads.List("snippet,replies");
            commentThreadsListRequest.VideoId = Youtube.Video.ID;
            commentThreadsListRequest.Order = CommentThreadsResource.ListRequest.OrderEnum.Relevance;
            commentThreadsListRequest.MaxResults = 1;
            var commentThreadsListResult = commentThreadsListRequest.Execute();
            foreach (var CommentThread in commentThreadsListResult.Items)
            {
                var commentListRequest = youtube.Comments.List("snippet");
                commentListRequest.Id = CommentThread.Id;
                var commentListResult = commentListRequest.Execute();


                foreach (var Item in commentListResult.Items)
                {
                    CommentThreadIDs.Add(Item.Id);
                }
                MessageBox.Show("COUNT:" + CommentThread.Replies.Comments.Count);
                foreach (var Reply in CommentThread.Replies.Comments)
                {
                    CommentThreadIDs.Add(Reply.Id);
                }
            }
        }
```

I have checked my API and the video ID. They are all fine as I can request alot of other information.
I have tested this with several videos, but all videos where the first comment have more than 5 replies, it fails to get them all.

The result (Message Box with "Count:") I get (the amount of replies I get in `CommentThread.Replies.Comments` is 5. No matter what I do. Going to next page with a token does not work either as it is empty.

Does anyone know why it only returns 5 comments instead of more?

Comment: `commentThreadsListRequest.MaxResults = 1;` What does this do?

Comment: @mjwills from all commentThreads of the video I selected, it will only return one result (which is the top comment) due to `commentThreadsListRequest.Order = CommentThreadsResource.ListRequest.OrderEnum.Relevance;`

Comment: If you solved your question, wait a day or so and click the green checkmark at the upper-left of your answer. That marks your question as solved in the UI. Putting “SOLVED” in the title does not mark it as solved.

Comment: The maxResults parameter specifies the maximum number of items that should be returned in the result set.  you sould really just leave it at the default of twenty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer with help of someone.
The problem was that I set the ID of a commentThread to a comment ID.
Instead I have to set the commentThread ID to the parent ID.

The following code fully replaces my old code if anyone ever needs it.

```
YouTubeService yts = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { ApiKey = "12345" });

var commentThreadsListRequest = yts.CommentThreads.List("snippet,replies");
commentThreadsListRequest.VideoId = "uywOqrvxsUo";
commentThreadsListRequest.Order = CommentThreadsResource.ListRequest.OrderEnum.Relevance;
commentThreadsListRequest.MaxResults = 1;
var commentThreadResult = commentThreadsListRequest.Execute().Items.First();

var commentListRequest = yts.Comments.List("snippet");
commentListRequest.Id = commentThreadResult.Id;
commentListRequest.MaxResults = 100;

var commentListResult = commentListRequest.Execute();
var comments = commentListResult.Items.Select(x => x.Snippet.TextOriginal).ToList();
```